# Do red lasers shoot longer than green ones?

Tags: visible-light, electromagnetic-radiation, laser

I am aware of the fact that our eyes are most sensible to green color and therefore green lasers seem stronger than other colors when being scattered through the air. However, since red wavelength are longer than green and not as easily subjected to Reyleigh scattering as green, shouldn't red lasers be able to hit more distant surfaces?

Comment: On the other hand, the diffraction-limited divergence angle of the beam will be greater for a longer emission wavelength. Which of these effects dominates in practical situations I'm not sure.

Comment: there is enough power even in cheaper lasers so that the beam (many of the photons) can escape the atmosphere and travel a great distance into space. Green or red does not matter.